# Python read user input before enter key pressed, and replace user value in some cases

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python, coming over from PHP.  The following is something I have not even done in PHP, and also after searching I don't see this.  I've spent some time figuring out how to be concise on this so here goes:

I want to use something similar to the python `input("Enter a value here:")` for running a CLI application but with two modifications:

1. Instead of reading the prompt only upon the enter key being entered, I read the user's input on each keystroke (I don't know if there's a distinct keyup or keydown or etc. in Python as in JavaScript, "keypress" would be fine), and
2. If the user press a certain key such as the up arrow or down arrow (which I believe to be `^[[A` and `^[[B` respectively) then I want to replace all the user input so far with something else.

As you might guess, the intent is to be able to up/down through command history.  I can handle the part about filling in values from a read file if I just have the above.

One more thing, I have a MacBook, and Python 3 available.  Thank you!

-- EDIT --
After suggestions, I've edited this to state that I'll accept an answer in Py3 vs 2, and found I can run Py3 by just `python3 myfile.py` so answer edited accordingly

Comment: Python 2 has been totally shelved and deprecated, for more than a year and a half now. Definitely use 3.x. Also, it sounds like you would need something like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html); have you researched/looked into it?

Comment: For a simple command history just do `import readline`

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for two things here. 1) History 2) Key-Capture. Unless you are going line completion, I dont really think you need to capture individual keystokes. As mentioned, check the `readline` docs for history

Comment: Suggesting curses or readline is almost tantamount to handing me a russian dictionary when I have to write a doctoral thesis on Climate Science, that said, an example of either 1) or 2) would be helpful.  And I can run `python3` for my command it appears, so I'll edit the above.

Comment: Python 2 is dead. long live Python 3.

Comment: @OliverWilliams, It may be time to learn some Russian then. There are good examples a Google search away, for both `readline` and `curses`

Comment: `curses` is one approach, but if you really just want to do a couple of things related to keystrokes rather than implementing a full cursor-based UI maybe https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/ is the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick code sample using the `keyboard` module (which you can install with `pip install keyboard`):

```
import keyboard


string = ""
while True:
    event = keyboard.read_event()
    if event.event_type != 'down':
        continue
    if event.name == 'up':
        string = "something else"
    else:
        string += event.name
    print(string)
```